# Can WinRT use reflection to find and invoke superclass constructor?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have the following Windows Runtime solution setup:

In a DLL referenced by my EXE

```
public abstract class BaseClass {

    public BaseClass(Guid id, string name) {
        //...
    }

}
```

In the EXE

```
public sealed class DerivedClass : BaseClass {

}
```

In the DLL, also, there is another class which uses a subtype of `BaseClass` that is designated at runtime.  I figured that since the base class has the constructor, I would be able to instantiate it like so:

```
//this._userType holds the type of DerivedClass
BaseClass foo = (BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(this._userType, id, name);
```

However, it informs me that the constructor cannot be found.  So I went and found other answers that said I could use `Type`'s `GetConstructor()` method, but that doesn't seem to be present in WinRT.  There is a `DeclaredConstructors` property but that only lists constructors that are explicitly declared in `DerivedClass`.  `DerivedClass` doesn't need to do anything in addition to `BaseClass` for this particular constructor, so I'd hate to just write out an explicit constructor that calls `base` but if that is the only option, then let me know (I confirmed that this approach works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# super class constructors classes are not automatically inherited by derived classes. Let's say you have a super class with a constructor:

```
public class BaseClass
{

    public BaseClass(Guid id, string name)
    {
        //...
    }

}
```

If you don't declare a constructor with the same set of parameters on the derived class, it won't be available for it. You need to call the super class constructor from the derived class constructor to make it available:

```
public sealed class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(Guid id, string name) 
        : base(id, name)
    { }
}
```

Also, the derived class constructor always needs to call a super class constructor. If you have a parameterless super class constructor, you don't need to explicitly call it as it will be called automatically. Keep in mind, though, that implicitly the parameterless constructor will always be called, not the one with matching parameters. In all other cases you need to call the selected super class constructor explicitly with the above syntax.

Another point worth mentioning is that abstract classes don't really need public constructors as they can be only be called from their derived classes, since an abstract class can't be directly instantiated. That means you really should make them `protected`. The compiler won't complain but most of style check tools will give warnings if you have public constructors on abstract classes.

One last thing: you really should avoid using reflection unless it's absolutely necessary. It affects performance and also breaks type safety, i.e. you'll get errors at runtime instead at compile time.

Comment: Oh right, I just carelessly typed the constructor as public (public was on my mind after reading that Activator only picks up public constructors).  I didn't realize that C# didn't implicitly inherit its superclass constructors, I guess C# and I have spent too much time apart.  As far as reflection goes, I am aware of the pitfalls but these classes are designed for serialization and transmission through sockets so there is not another immediately obvious way to do it as far as I'm aware.  Thanks for all the advice though!